# Message in gift options with maximum size allowed

Tags: magento2, giftmessage

I need help, I would like to set a maximum size for the message text area in gift options in magento 2.

[image]

I'm a beginner in magento development, and any help will be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this below page in your custom module

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="custom_tab" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Custom Tab</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="custom" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Custom Settings</label>
            <tab>custom_tab</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::module_config</resource>
            <group id="gift" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Gift Message Configuration</label>
                <field id="message_size" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Message Box Size</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Then you update in textarea page:

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$scopeConfig= $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');
$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
?>
<textarea maxlength="<?php echo $this->scopeConfig->getValue('custom/gift/message_size', $storeScope); ?>"></textarea>
```

Then run:

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I came to that conclusion. But I would like to make this dynamic and configurable in the admin panel.

Comment: Could you tell me a way to do this?

Comment: By this above process you can set max size from magento admin.

Comment: Thank you! I regret the delay in responding. But only today did I reach the goal, following your code as an example.